# Create an S4 class object in R with some of the arguments passed using the ellipsis

Tags: r, r-s4, do.call

How could I use some of the arguments passed to a function using the ellipsis to create a new object of an S4 class, while naming the arguments?

Example:

```
foo <- function(a, ...){

  cur_args <- lapply(match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)[-1], deparse)

  args_to_keep <- names(cur_args) %in%  slotNames("myClass1")

  newClassObj <- new("myClass1", what can go here??? )
}
```

Is there any way to use *do.call* and comply with the types of the slots of the class / retain the type as it was passed to foo?

```
newClassObj <- do.call( "new", as.list( c("Class"="myClass1", cur_args[args_to_keep] )) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea,
you just have to create the list of arguments passed to `new` correctly:

```
setClass("A", slots=c(x="numeric"))
foo <- function(...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    valid_slots <- dots[intersect(names(dots), slotNames("A"))]
    do.call(new, c(list(Class="A"), valid_slots))
}

> foo(x=1, y=2)
An object of class "A"
Slot "x":
[1] 1
```

`c` can be used to append lists to each other,
so you just need to wrap `Class="A"` in a list.

Comment: Thanks; so, I will have to merge the names of the arguments besides the ellipsis to get the complete list.

Comment: You can simply do something like `valid_slots$a <- a`, or use your approach with `match.call`.